# Splitting Protractor Tests into different Sessions on BrowserStack Automate

Tags: protractor, e2e-testing, browserstack

I'm running a Protractor suite on BrowserStack and am searching for a way to split my suite's tests into different Sessions on BrowserStack. So far I've had success by setting `restartBrowserBetweenTests` to true in my configuration file but this doubles my suite's execution time. Is there any way to split the sessions when a new test executes without the *restartBrowserBetweenTests* variable?